# QTableView: When selecting cells, how do I make the first cell selected the current index?

Tags: c++, qt, indexing, selection, qtableview

I have a simple class which inherits QTableView and I want the following behavior: when the user selects a few cells, I want the first cell selected to be set as the current index.

So for example if I select from (0, 0) towards (2, 2), when I start typing the text would show up in (0, 0), not (2, 2) which seems to be the default.

I have tried overriding the setSelection function with the following:

```
void SampleTable::setSelection(const QRect &rect, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags command)
{
    if((command & QItemSelectionModel::Current) != 0)
    {
        QModelIndex curr = indexAt(rect.topLeft());
        selectionModel()->select(curr, QItemSelectionModel::Current);

        command ^= QItemSelectionModel::Current;
    }
    QTableView::setSelection(rect, command);
}
```

but to no avail.  It seems to have something to do with the mouse events, but I can't quite locate the problem in the source code and I'm hoping there's an easier way anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and how to fix it, but it's not pretty.  The problem is in the mouse moved event for a QAbstractItemView.  After much debugging and searching through the source code I found this in qabstractitemview.cpp:

```
void QAbstractItemView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
...
if (index.isValid()
        && (index != d->selectionModel->currentIndex())
        && d->isIndexEnabled(index))
    d->selectionModel->setCurrentIndex(index, QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate);
}
```

I fixed it by giving my class a QModelIndex member which stores the last location of the top left QModelIndex (set in my overriden version of setSelection like above) and then I overrode the mouseMoveEvent with this:

```
void SampleTable::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    if (state() == ExpandingState || state() == CollapsingState || state() == DraggingState || state() == EditingState)
            return;
    if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)) {
        if (m_topLeft.isValid())
        {
            selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(m_topLeft, QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

Not a pretty solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `QtableWidget` class has a signal `itemSelectionChanged()`, connect it to your custom slot. In that slot, use `selectedIndexes()` to get all indexes, then use `setCurrentIndex()` to set the cell which you want to be the current index.

Comment: I'm using QTableView, not QTableWidget so the signal isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? If you'd like the user to edit/select a single cell only, use [setSelectionBehaviour](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop) to force this. Otherwise you could try chinfoo's idea but make sure to communicate the behavior in a way the user is able to understand it (i.e. he's able to see that his edit will change the first cell/row).